# Check which values, if any, are present in every column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table whose columns' headers are dates. Each column (date) has a series of IDs, like below:

| jan/18 | fev/18 | mar/18 | abr/18 | mai/18 | jun/18 | jul/18 | ago/18 | set/18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 | 0000022 | 0000023 | 0000024 | 0000025 | 0000026 | 0000027 |
| 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 | 0000022 | 0000023 | 0000024 | 0000025 |
| 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 | 0000022 | 0000023 | 0000024 |
| 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 |
| 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 | 0000022 | 0000023 |
| 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 |
| 0000002 | 0000003 | 0000004 | 0000005 | 0000006 | 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 |
| 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 |
| 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 | 0000022 | 0000023 | 0000024 | 0000025 | 0000026 |
| 0000004 | 0000005 | 0000006 | 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 |
| 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 |
| 0000003 | 0000004 | 0000005 | 0000006 | 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 |
| 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 |
| 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 | 0000022 |
| 0000001 | 0000002 | 0000003 | 0000004 | 0000005 | 0000006 | 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 |
| 0000006 | 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 |
| 0000005 | 0000006 | 0000007 | 0000008 | 0000009 | 0000010 | 0000011 | 0000012 | 0000013 |
| 0000012 | 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 |
| 0000013 | 0000014 | 0000015 | 0000016 | 0000017 | 0000018 | 0000019 | 0000020 | 0000021 |

I need to find which IDs are present in every single column. For instance, I know that the IDs 000009 to 000019 are present in every column from jan/2018 all the way to set/2018.

Is there a way to list all the IDs present in every column in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: You really need to sort out your table design. The way you have it, you need to add a column to the table every month. This should be normalized into rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SQL Intersect](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php#:%7E:text=SQL%3A%20INTERSECT%20Operator%201%20Description.%20The%20SQL%20INTERSECT,...%206%20Example%20-%20Using%20ORDER%20BY.%20) to find the common results from multiple queries, in this case query each column as a separate query and *intersect* the results.

```
SELECT [jan/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [fev/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [mar/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [abr/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [mai/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [jun/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [jul/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [ago/18] FROM table.data
INTERSECT
SELECT [set/18] FROM table.data
```

Comment: I've never even seen a reason to use `INTERSECT` before, well done!

Comment: @Chris Schaller  me neither .... but  thanks for the edit.

Comment: @IsPHPCool7 yw!  IMO its not a best practice to have columns in table that refer to fixed dates. ( maybe this is not in your control ).  What happens is that in this case you will need a new table for every year and worse you will need to change your queries too. ( even in the case that you have no need for a table other than for 2018 )

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use `apply` to unpivot the data and then aggregate:

```
select col
from t cross apply
     (values (t.[jan/18], 1),
             (t.[fev/18], 2),
             . . .
     ) v(col, which)
group by col
having count(distinct which) = 12;
```

The advantage of this over `intersect` is that it only scans the table once.  `Intersect` removes duplicates, which is should be similar to `group by` in performance -- however, I am not sure if a series of `intersect`s removes them once or eleven times.  This seems safer from a performance perspective.

Comment: I wanted to post an unpivot like this, but intersect is probably more accessible to OP in this case. it's the `count() = 12` that annoys me the most, the magic value of `12` is very specific to an individual query and although obvious to some, its an easy value to get wrong when you apply this back to the production scenario. Especially given that there are not 12 columns in OP's dataset ;)

Comment: Actually @GordonLinoff this query shows us the columns that have all the values,  it doesn't resolve the Ids that are in each column. so its a flawed example of how you could un-pivot the data. Becareful posting partial queries like this where you expect OP to fill too many gaps.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller . . . I have no idea what you are referring to.  This shows the value that are in all the columns, not columns that have all the values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I cant get this to work on a 3 column table with the last line (having clause) set = 3 ... can you please explain ?

Comment: @objectNotFound . . . That is `cross apply` as mentioned in the text, not `cross join`.

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle comparing this solution to the INTERSECT version. You can see that the `CROSS APPLY` query as it stands does not tell us which record Ids from the original table are in all of the columns.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b614a/4

Comment: @GordonLinoff makes sense now, should have seen that myself, in SO posts like this we should use aliases more, that would have expressed the intent a bit better, I was picturing it as an UNPIVOT in which case the quotes are valid.